# Is it possible to use a 2.4GHz wireless keyboard and mouse with an Xbox Series X?

Tags: controllers, xbox-series-x-series-s

I am wondering if it is possible to use such a control combination on an Xbox Series X? I am asking because I'm coming from a PC gaming background and it seems a more natural combination for me.

I have heard that wired devices do work and that Bluetooth basically doesn't work, but the situation seems somewhat confused for devices that use a 2.4GHz USB dongle. A lot of people have said "probably" and even then *any* mouse or keyboard seems restricted due to incompatibilities with some software (some games just won't work). Given this, is getting an Xbox Series X primarily with the intention of playing games using a wireless mouse and keyboard risky compared to the alternative of getting an equivalent gaming PC?

Comment: There are aftermarket tools like XIM that enable you to use a mouse & keyboard in any game by simulating controller inputs. The games aren't designed for it so it may not always work well. Online multiplayer games may consider using this type of adapter as a form of cheating. I'd suggest sticking with PC gaming if you don't want to use console gamepads.